# Calling HTML tags from another file in Scrapy spider class and parse them

Tags: parsing, scrapy, css-selectors

I am new to Python and Scrapy. So, I am not aware if the following scenario can be achieved.
Therefore, let me know if it's possible.

I know that this is how usually Scrapy works :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import Allitems

class newspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_code"
    start_urls = ['URL_Name']

    def parse(self, response):
        class_name = ".product-list--list-item" 
        product_name_tag = "./div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a/text()"
   
        selector1 = response.css(class_name)

        for items in selector1:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=Allitems(), selector=items)
            loader.add_xpath('Product_Name', product_name_tag)
            yield loader.load_item()
```

How to create a file in which I can add all the HTML tags which are declared in variables and call them in a Spider class and parse those HTML tags via selectors ?

For example -

**Sample.txt :**

```
class_name = ".product-list--list-item" 
product_name_tag = "./div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a/text()"
```

**Spider file :**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import Allitems

class newspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_code"
    start_urls = ['URL_Name']

def parse(self, response):

*** Call Sample.txt ***

            selector1 = response.css(class_name)
            for items in selector1:
                loader = ItemLoader(item=Allitems(), selector=items)
                loader.ad+d_xpath('Product_Name', product_name_tag)
                yield loader.load_item()
```

In all the websites, the HTML tags might change. Therefore, I want to keep the HTML tags declaration separately in a file and parsing & scraping of each item in another file.

Comment: My suggestion would be to think about xpath selectors which are broad and depend on attributes rather than multiple child elements like div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a/text() you have there. Rather than using a text file of selectors. There isn't that much difference between changing your code if the scrape doesn't happen and editing a text file. The response.xpath(//div[contains(@class,"ATTRIBUTE")]') for example is quite broad.

Comment: @AaronS yes, i accept your point. In most of the cases, I would have used broad and depend on attributes. Only in few cases, i used multiple child elements. Those I will be changing soon to broad attributes. Anyways, I want to keep the HTML tags in a separate file and call them in Spider class for parsing. If there is a way, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a `sample.py` (instead of your sample.txt) so you can import the variables. You can still do it with `.txt`, but you would have to load it as text file and parse through it. While having a `sample.py` allows for importing precisely:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import Allitems
from sample import class_name, product_name_tag  


class newspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_code"
    start_urls = ['URL_Name']

def parse(self, response):

    selector1 = response.css(class_name)
    for items in selector1:
        loader = ItemLoader(item=Allitems(), selector=items)
        loader.ad+d_xpath('Product_Name', product_name_tag)
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: Great answer @renatodvc. Thanks a lot for your assistance. Since I am very new to Python, I couldn't find this solution before itself. Anyways, I tried to up vote, but since my reputations are low, I couldn't.